# Strange type behavior

Tags: java, types, overloading

I'm trying to implement a CAS like thing in Java, but I'm struggling with the types and method selection.

When I add the two subtypes, everything is fine.
When I add a subtype with a supertype an infinite recursion occurs.
When the supertype is casted down its fine again and when I add a supertype to a subtype the same recursion occurs again.

Can someone explain what's happening here and what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class MathMain{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Constant constant = new Constant(1);
        constant.add(constant);
        MathObject mathObject = (MathObject)constant;
        constant.add(mathObject);
        constant.add((Constant)mathObject);
        mathObject.add(constant);
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class MathObject{
    public abstract MathObject add(MathObject addend);
    public abstract MathObject substract(MathObject subtrahend);
}
```

```
public class Constant extends MathObject{
    public final double c;

    public Constant(double c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    public MathObject add(MathObject that){
        return that.add((Constant)this);
    }

    public MathObject substract(MathObject that){
        return that.substract((Constant)this);
    }

    public Constant add(Constant addend){
        return new Constant(c + addend.c);
    }

    public Constant substract(Constant subtrahend){
        return new Constant(c - subtrahend.c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that method overload resolution is determined at compile time while method overriding is determined at runtime.

```
mathObject.add(constant)
```

chooses the `MathObject add(MathObject addend)` method, which is the only `add` method available for `MathObject`.

At runtime, since the runtime type of `mathObject` is `Constant`, `MathObject add(MathObject that)` of `Constant` is executed, and it calls `that.add((Constant)this)`. Since the type of `that` is `MathObject`, again `MathObject add(MathObject addend)` is chosen, which means your method is calling itself in an infinite recursion.

The only way your `Constant add(Constant addend)` will be called by the `that.add((Constant)this)` expression is if the compile time type of `that` was `Constant`, since `MathObject` doesn't have an `add` method that accepts a `Constant` argument.

Now, for the cases that work :

```
constant.add(constant)
constant.add((Constant)mathObject)
```

both call `Constant add(Constant addend)` directly, since the compile type of `constant` is `Constant` and the method with the more specific argument types is chosen.

I don't know if that's a good solution, but one way to get over the infinite recursion is to check the type of the argument :

```
public MathObject add(MathObject that){
    if (that instanceof Constant)
        return add((Constant) that);
    else
        that.add((Constant)this); // note that the casting here only makes
                                  // sense if MathObject has an add method
                                  // that takes a Constant. otherwise is makes
                                  // no difference
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this oversight :)
I've thought of a workaround cloning the callee and calling back the caller, but how would I do this for Objects that are required to preserve the original pointer, e.g. a Variable?

Comment: Also why doesnt Java realise that `MathObject add(MathObject)` `return that.add(this)` this is actually a Constant instead of the declared MathObject even when the method is obviously located in the Constant class and not the MathObject class? By the way that workaround above doesn't work either for some reason.

Comment: @S.Klumpers the argument `that` can be any sub-class of `MathObject`. And since the base `MathObject` doesn't have an `add(Constant addend)` method, it can't call that method when you write `that.add(this)`, even if the runtime type of `that` is `Constant`.

Comment: Having an abstract `MathObject add(Constant that)` on its own has helped, sure its ugly but it works. I guess I'll move it to codereview.